# How to compare stored date and time with SimpleDateFormat and display notification?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, simpledateformat

In my application I want to display the notification based on the time that user have already set and I am storing the Date and Time into local database. 
I am getting the Date and Time from Local database and comparing with **SimpleDateFormat** and parsing with  **Date** like this

```
SimpleDateFormat yourDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
Date date = null;
     try { 
          String date_time = "17-11-2017 15:10";
          date = yourDateFormat.parse(date_time);

     } catch (ParseException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Parsing date time failed", e);
     }
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTime(date);

     Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
     if (calendar.compareTo(current) <= 0) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Date/Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     } else {
          AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(RemainderActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);             
          PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);
          alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent);

    }
```

Some devices it is working fine like above 7.0 android version but below 7.0 versions it is showing `java.lang.NullPointerException` like this

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Date java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

and the error is showing here `date = yourDateFormat.parse(date_time);`.

Please help me out. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check this line year is wrong  String date_time = "17/11/207 15:10";

Comment: sorry, typo wrong. Original format is `String date_time = "17-11-2017 15:10";`

Comment: I have a hard time believing you can get that `NullPointerException` from that line. Are you sure this is the exact code that you are running?

Comment: @OleV.V. but I am getting this error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Date java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Wonder if you can check in a debugger whether `yourDateFormat` is null right after `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")` and again whether it is right before `yourDateFormat.parse(date_time)`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks. I have debugged the application. It is taking null in `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")`. I have solved the issue. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then problem is changed here is your new solution:

Before this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTime(date);
```

Add:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en","US")
```

and then replace:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

with:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
```

So it looks like this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en","US")
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
calendar.setTime(date);
```

Your whole code you provided will be like :

```
SimpleDateFormat yourDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
Date date = null;
 try { 
      String date_time = "17-11-2017 15:10";
      date = yourDateFormat.parse(date_time);

 } catch (ParseException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Parsing date time failed", e);
 }
 Locale locale = new Locale("en","US")
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
 calendar.setTime(date);

 Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
 if (calendar.compareTo(current) <= 0) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Date/Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 } else {
      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(RemainderActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);             
      PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);
      alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent);

}
```

Comment: Buddy if this works for you dont forget to mark this post as answer. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Buddy, if it works for anyone, we still don’t understand why. :-) Please explain how and why you think this may solve the OP’s problem. So we all may learn. Code-only answers are not helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan Sorry, Typo wrong. I'm using this method only `new SimpleDateFormat("17-11-2017 15:10");`.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes bro I added some details. Hope this will be helpful for people now. :)

Comment: Buddy I edited the solution. Follow my instructions now. This will work.

Comment: Look the edited answer this will work. And dont forget to mark this post as answer. Happy Coding :)

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

To get the date which user has selected u can use this,

```
private void getSelectedDate() {
        String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        String new_date = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("DATE SELECTED IS ::    " + new_date);
        your_textview.setText(new_date);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is lots of codes, you can simply set alarm with just few lines of codes. What you need to do is to get the date as a milliseconds [DatePicker](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) or other API, and configure your AlarmManager to fire when that time expires. Like this:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(RemainderActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);             
          PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);
          alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
        60000, alarmIntent);
```

The above code will fire the BroadcastReceiver every 1 minute(60000milliseconds). Just replace the time with the user set date.